# Averageifs using OR function

Tags: excel

I need the values in column T to be averaged if

1) value in column O to be less than the value in cell M56
AND
2) value in column P to be greater than the value in cell M56
OR
3) value in column P to be blank

so I need 1) to be true AND 2) or 3) to be true

```
=AVERAGEIFS(T:T,O:O,"<="&M56,P:P">="&M56)
```

The equation above covers 2 of the criteria, but I am not sure how to next the OR function on the 2nd criteria in the above equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straightforward is to break it into sumifs/countifs like below:

```
=(SUMIFS($T:$T,$O:$O,"<=" & $M$56, $P:$P, ">=" & $M$56) + SUMIFS($T:$T,$O:$O,"<=" & $M$56, $P:$P, "") / (COUNTIFS($O:$O,"<=" & $M$56, $P:$P, ">=" & $M$56) + COUNTIFS($O:$O,"<=" & $M$56, $P:$P, ""))
```

Comment: That logic would work. Is there not a way to actually next the OR function in the averageifs equation? Asking for simplicity and it will make it easier for others to understand the equation once this worksheet gets shared to others.

Comment: No, averageifs does not allow for OR functionality.